# Django model fields mapping: Modelform vs ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model.The required property of the fields is not same for the Modelform and Modelserializer. Please see the below example

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)  
    streetname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Checking the fields mapping with ModelForm

```
class Testform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model=Test
       fields=['name','streetname']
```

Properties of the fields are:

```
 name -> required=true  (may be because of null=false or its the default value)
 streetname -> required=true (since default value is true)
```

Checking the fields mapping with ModelSerializer:

```
class TestSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields=['name','streetname']
```

the field properties are serialized as:

```
name -> required=true  (may be because of null=false)
streetname -> required=false (although the default is True, its showing false)
```

How to understand the Modelserialize's streetname required property.

Comment: "since default value is true" but there's no default on your model.

Comment: `streetname -> required=false`: I havent added any default for this in the model. So it required should be true